# Which one should we prefer for our project Asp.net mvc OR asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

We are starting a new website for our client(Hospital).
Our web application should target desktop, tablet, mobile users.
For this which one is preferred Asp.net mvc OR Asp.net web api?
For front end we are using kendo ui framework for displaying UI.

Comment: You seem to want to choose a framework on how it is marketed, if I read your comments correctly. The "newest and fastest" library isn't always the best for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different technologies and are used for different purposes.  MVC is for building a website using the Model-View-Controller paradigm.  You would serve up the UI of your application using asp.net MVC.  The views you deliver would use Kendo UI to materialize the user experience.

Web API is used for creating REST services and does not produce a UI purely on its own.  When people discuss web services or AJAX, web api is what they are referring to.  Basically, you send requests to the web api, and it returns JSON results that your javascript (or Kendo UI) can render without refreshing the page.

Of course, MVC and web api can be combined in one project, but its usually better to separate them into their own projects to have a true separation of concerns.

My suggestion is that you read up more on the difference between the two technologies to get a better understanding of what your solution architecture should look like:

- [web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
- [mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the esiest way will be using asp.net MVC project with [Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC VSExtensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65b78c2c-951e-43a8-bae7-f9039f59fb9b). You could always add web api to your project.

Comment: Hi, If i use web api is there any problem or defects to our project?

Comment: No, you can add MVC later if it will be needed. With KendouUI templates it will be just easier to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your UI you need the asp.net mvc or asp.net web forms. Web api is like an HTTP service which you can from javascript and redner stuff on UI. So its totally depends on the your requirement whether you need to have some UI render from the javascript or not?

Comment: Yes jalpesh, Using kendo grid i can comunicate with asp.net mvc as well as asp.net web api, Iam interested to use web api as it is light weight and latest, any draw backs if i go with web api?

Comment: No there is no drawbacks for using this. But do you know Kendo UI is not free. So make sure you are able to pay licence fee.

Comment: Yes, our company has already bought licence, I think no prob if i use below is the tech we r using 4 our new project   C#, 
Asp.Net,
Asp.Net Mvc 4.0,
Asp.Net Webapi,
Entity Framework 5.0,
Linq,
SqlServer 2008,
Visual Studio 2012(IDM),
TFS(Environment),
XML, 
Javascript,
Jquery,
Json,
Kendo UI,
HTML5,
CSS3, . .

Comment: Then its fine. Its one of paid component. We are also using that in our project.

Comment: my blog contains all the information